# Copy-pasting data in .csv files according to dates

Tags: r

I have the following issue to solve.

I have separate folders with precipitation data at daily time-step (for years 2008-2021) stored in a .csv files, which are named in the following manner: "249180020_2008_combined", where "249180020" is a station code, and "2008" represents a year. In the .csv files the data are stored in three columns: Station_code; Date; Precipitation. The problem is that for some days (or months) there are missing values.

Therefore, my goal is to create a new (or overwrite the existing) .csv file with complete dates for every year and copy-paste into it the corresponding data according to the data. On the dates where there are no data to be pasted in, I would like to have NA values.

In total, I have more than 300 meteo stations and I would like to do it in a loop. Could anyone help me with that problem?

Please find below a short reproducible example of the data:

```
structure(list(Station_code = c(249180020L, 249180020L, 249180020L,  249180020L, 249180020L, 249180020L, 249180020L, 249180020L, 249180020L,  249180020L, 249180020L, 249180020L, 249180020L, 249180020L), Date = c("1/1/2008 6:00", "1/2/2008 6:00", "1/4/2008 6:00", 
"1/5/2008 6:00", "1/6/2008 6:00", "1/7/2008 6:00", "1/9/2008 6:00", 
"1/10/2008 6:00", "1/11/2008 6:00", "1/12/2008 6:00", "1/14/2008 6:00", 
"1/15/2008 6:00", "1/16/2008 6:00", "1/17/2008 6:00"), Precipitation = c("0.5", 
"0.1", "0", "0", "0", "2.9", "0.1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

Many thanks for your kind help!

Comment: What the structure of files or folders in you system ?

Comment: The structure looks like that "H:\Luca_Brocca\Scripts\Processing_rain_gauge_data\Processed_data\2008\Combined". In the Combined folder I have the precipitation data. I have other folders for 2009-2021 in the same structure.

Answer (score 1):

So here's how you can expand the example data to have an entry for each day of 2008:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(glue)

df <-  structure(list(Station_code = c(249180020L, 249180020L, 249180020L,  249180020L, 249180020L, 249180020L, 249180020L, 249180020L, 249180020L,  249180020L, 249180020L, 249180020L, 249180020L, 249180020L), 
                      Date = c("1/1/2008 6:00", "1/2/2008 6:00", "1/4/2008 6:00", 
                               "1/5/2008 6:00", "1/6/2008 6:00", "1/7/2008 6:00", "1/9/2008 6:00", 
                               "1/10/2008 6:00", "1/11/2008 6:00", "1/12/2008 6:00", "1/14/2008 6:00", 
                               "1/15/2008 6:00", "1/16/2008 6:00", "1/17/2008 6:00"), 
                      Precipitation = c("0.5", 
                                        "0.1", "0", "0", "0", "2.9", "0.1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                        "0", "0")), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))


 
# expand example data to each day of 2008:
df$Date <- lubridate::mdy_hm(df$Date) # format Date column as Date

# key step: get combination of Station code and all dates in 2008:
df_alldays <- expand.grid(Date = seq(mdy_hm("1-1-2008 6:00"),mdy_hm("12-31-2008 6:00"), by = "day"),
                          Station_code = unique(df$Station_code))

# now merge that with observations
df_alldates <- df_alldays %>% left_join(df)

df_alldates # contains all dates with missing for days without Precipitation
```

#### loop through 2008 - 2021

Now let's expand this to more years, based on the folder structure you mentioned - assuming these are csv files with identical column names:

```
all_measures <- 
 map_dfr(2008:2021, function(dir1){
    csv_files <- list.files(path = glue::glue("H:/Luca_Brocca/Scripts/Processing_rain_gauge_data/Processed_data/",dir1,"/Combined"), 
                            full.names = TRUE,
                            pattern = "\\.csv$") # get all csv files in directory
    # csv_files contains the full path to all csvs in the directory
    # now let's read them in using purrr::map 
    df <- map_dfr(csv_files,.f = ~read.csv(.x)) # add csv options if necessary
    df$Date <- lubridate::mdy_hm(df$Date) # format Date column as Date
    df_alldays <- expand.grid(Date = seq(mdy_hm(glue::glue("1-1-",dir1," 6:00")),
                                         mdy_hm(glue::glue("12-31-",dir1," 6:00")), 
                                         by = "day"),
                            Station_code = unique(df$Station_code))
    return(df_alldays %>% left_join(df))
  })
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! For the exemplary data this exactly what I wanted to obtain. Thanks a lot. However, when I try to run the loop you have written I am getting a following error " Warning: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
Warning:  1 failed to parse.
Error in seq.POSIXt(mdy_hm(glue::glue("1-1-", dir1, " 6:00")), mdy_hm(glue::glue("12-31-",  : 
  'to' must be of length 1" . I have tried to fix it myself, but have not succeed. All .csv file follow the same column names structure.

Comment: Classic coding error: I misplaced a parenthesis, apologies.

Comment: Thank you for your help last week. It was really helpful. I almost there. When I try to execute the code right now I got following errors: Warning: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
Joining, by = c("Date", "Station_code")
Warning: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
Joining, by = c("Date", "Station_code")
Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: `Date`.
Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: `Station_code`.
Joining, by = "Date"

Comment: Any thoughts on what could be the problem? I have checked the formatting of dates in .csv files and it seems to be fine.